# Prove that there is a nontrivial ring homomorphism from $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]/(x,y)^2$ to $\mathbb{C}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am currently studying for my qualifying exam in algebra. I am thinking about an old question that asks you to look at $R = \mathbb{Q}[x,y]/I$ where $I=(x,y)^2$. It asks for the following three things:

1. Find all ideals in $R$.
2. Describe the units in $R$.
3. Show that there is a nontrivial ring homomorphism from $R$ to $\mathbb{C}$.

Here is a screenshot of the question in its original form:

[image]

Usually I would proceed using the correspondence theorem for part 1.  I am thinking that the only ideals of $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ containg $I$ are $(x,y)$, $(x^2,y)$ and $(x,y^2)$. However, I don't know how to justify that these are the only ideals containing $I$.

The units in $R$ are $\{ a + bx + cy : a,b,c \in \mathbb{Q} \}$. We should be able to equate coefficients in 
$$ 1 = (a + bx + cy)(a' + b'x + c'y)$$
We get the system:
\begin{align*}
1 &= aa' \\
0 &= ab' + a'b \\
0 &= ac' + a'c
\end{align*}
since $a'$ is completely determined by $a$, so are $b'$ and $c'$ determined by the given $b$ and $c$ and the existence of $a'$. So there elements are all invertible. So every element with a constant term in $R/I$ is invertible. Moreover, any element that doesn't have a constant term is not invertible (this is clear). So we have found all the units.

It is still unclear to me how to recover $\mathbb{C}$ from taking a quotient. Since we have found all the ideals in $R$, one of the ideals listed in part 1 (taking the quotient with $I$) must be precisely the kernel of the map that $R$ to $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: The title does not reflect the question: #3 does not say $R \cong \mathbb C$.

Comment: Presumably the confusion arises because I have used $I$ to mean separate things on both occasions? I will change it to $J$.

Comment: Dear @misogrumpy, You should change the title to reflect the actual question you asked. The claim made in the current title is false.

Comment: Is there a substantial difference between question 3 and the claim in the title?  It is possible that I am misunderstanding the questions, so I will attempt to plaster a screen shot of the question in the original post.

Comment: I would like to point out that the proposed answer for part a) does not capture every ideal. Consider the ideal $(x^2, xy, y^2, x+y) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}[x,y]$.

Comment: @BrianShin You're right! I missed this one. I have seen questions like this asked about PID's, where ideal containment is explicitly given in terms of divisors ( $(a) \subseteq (b)$ if and only if $b \mid a$).

I guess that the ideal you pointed out is the pullback of $(x+y) \subseteq R$. In any case, I'm still not sure how to show that all possible ideals have been accounted for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is only one homomorphism.  You need to send $x$ to an element of $\mathbb C$ that squares to zero, but the only such element is $0$, and similarly for $y$, and so all that is left is to determine the image of $\mathbb Q$.  However, since $1$ is sent to $1$, the requirements of a homomorphism guarantee that $n$ is sent to $n$, and then $p/q$ is sent to $p/q$.  Therefore, $\mathbb Q$ is sent to the copy of $\mathbb Q$ that we normally think of sitting inside the complex numbers, $x$ and $y$ are both sent to zero, and this actually determines a well defined homomorphism.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I wouldn't have expected this to be the \textit{unique} nontrivial homomorphism.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the question in the title, which curiously does not appear in the body of the post, it's obvious that no, $\Bbb Q[x,y]/J$ is *not* isomorphic to $\Bbb C$. For example $\Bbb Q[x,y]$ is countable, hence $\Bbb Q[x,y]/J$ is countable.

Comment: Hi David. You're right. Verbatim, the question asks "prove that there is a nontrivial ring homomorhpism from $R$ to $\mathbb{C}$. I can change the questions to reflect that we aren't looking for just any map, but rather a ring homomorphism. Of course, if $J$ is the kernel of any such map, then $R/J$ is isomorphic to its image, namely $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: $R/J$ is countable and the image of a map to $\mathbb{C}$ will never be $\mathbb{C}$ itself which is uncountable

Comment: @misogrumpy "to $\Bbb C$" does not mean "onto $\Bbb C$". It's obvious that the image cannot be $\Bbb C$, because, as I pointed out, $\Bbb C$ is uncountable.

Comment: Ah, that would do it! One little word caused all this confusion. In that case, evaluation at 0 should be good enough. The kernel of such a map is $(x,y) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}[x,y]$. It fits the requirements since $(x,y) \supseteq I$ and $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq \mathbb{C}$.